# jQuery Navigation Centering Formula Only Runs Once

Tags: jquery, resize, margin, formula, centering

I have a formula I wrote to center the position of the navbar I made and it's onload.
Is there a function I have to rewrite it in to make it run again every time the window size is changed?

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('#left').css({ 'margin-left': (($(window).width())/2)-190 });
)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo `});` in `doc ready` closing, Try to enclose it in `.resize()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#left').css({ 'margin-left': ($(window).width()/2)-190 });
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: Oops, I must have switched them when I typed it out in here, haha. I don't like to copy and paste so it sticks in my memory.

Thanks! Worked flawlessly!